# Typescript incorrect interface for sequelize.Model.Update?

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I'm working with Sequelize and typescript. I'm using this definition [sequelize.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/sequelize/sequelize.d.ts)

I found a problem using the `model.update` method, this interface receive as first argument the values that will be updated, but this argument has a `TAttributes` Type. I think this argument should be of `string` type. because we can use this function by sending only a subset of TAttributes.

Let me put an example, if I have a model like this:

```
 Person.attribues: {
   id: number;
   field1: string;
   field2: number;
 }
```

and then, after create and persist an instance, I want update filed2, I should do something like this:

```
Person.update(
   {field2: 5},
   {where: {id: 1}}
)
```

for this example, I'm having an typescript error because the first argument expect something of type `Person.attributes` and I'm providing only the subset `{field2: 5}`

I already did a question in [github](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/10386/), what do you think about that? I'm thinking ok?

Comment: It's not very clear what the question is. Is there any technical problem you are having trouble fixing? Or do you just want feedback on the github issue? If feedback is what you want github is the place to get it not here.

Comment: @toskv, edited for clarity. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should use the attributes declaration of `sequelize.d.ts` with optional property names, exactly because of that.

In your case you will need to do :

```
interface PersonAttributes {
   id?: number;
   field1?: string;
   field2?: number;
}
```

By doing this, when you use update it will specifically allow you to update only one property.

You can check the examples in [sequelize-tests.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/sequelize/sequelize-tests.ts#L29) for further reference.

Comment: I'm not agree with this, because if you define `PersonalAttributes` with all its attributes as optional, when you create a new instnace, you can't control the mandatory attrs.

Comment: Unfortunately that's a drawback that can't be solved easily ( I am one of the main contributors of sequelize.d.ts ). Keep in mind that you can create another class method that is typesafed with the attributes you want.

Comment: I maintain the original idea, define the `values` argument as string. Duplicate is always the wrong way when you have a more simpler solution